# RSync Filter Rules

Tags: yaml, rsync

So my problem goes on like this:

I have a yml file at this directory /srv/PvP/plugins/Essentials/userdata/USERNAME.yml
The file contains information such as this:

```
timestamps:
  login: 1379189230018
  lastteleport: 1379188566255
  logout: 1379188894740
ipAddress: *.*.*.*
lastlocation:
  world: skyworld
  x: 2.878462237122215
  y: 101.0
  z: 134.80091939768792
  yaw: 0.0
  pitch: 0.0
nickname: §bAmir
money: '101980.0'
logoutlocation:
  world: skyblock
  x: -305.81015336936576
  y: 187.50846552474954
  z: -446.69999998807907
  yaw: -222.72388
  pitch: 13.428226
```

I want to rsync the data in this file to a different directory:

/srv/SB/plugins/Essentials/userdata/USERNAME.yml

But I ONLY want to sync the **money** line. Is there a way to do this with rsync?

Also if this helps there are around 10K files in the userdata directory.

Answer (score 0):

no, rsync is a file based tool.

you could use grep to extract some lines with a regex-based approach (you might want to use a tool that understands yaml here) and save the result to some file and then rsync that file.